# SRD-05VDC-SL-C 5V DC relay not working with XY-DJM-5V

Tags: usb, relay, receiver, 5v, switching

I'm just a beginner and need some assistance. below is a diagram of a 4CH reciever which works fine with some leds and it reports 5V positive on Data0 when holding channel 0 on the transmitter. What's not working is when attempting to use a 5V DC relay as shown in diagram, the relay clicks and seems to work fine with a direct input.

I'm using USB Powered socket which is 5V DC 0.5A I believe. I'm really puzzled while its not working.

[image: schematic]

SUGGESTED

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkWYPv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relay draws more current than that module can supply. If you keep doing such tests you may damage the receiver!

If you read the [SC2272-M4](http://www.datasheet4u.net/pdf/643896/SC/SC2272.html) datasheet, you'll see it can supply a maximum current of 3 mA. That [relay](http://www.datasheet-pdf.com/datasheet/Songle/720556/SRD-05VDC-SL-C.pdf.html) needs 89 mA at a 55 ohms coil resistance. So the load current is 5 / 55 = 0.09 A = 90 mA. Now, the minimum hFE of the transistor should be (0.09 / 0.003) x 5 = 150. The resistor between receiver and transistor base should be 0.2 x 55 x 150 = 1650 ohms. Choose 1.8 k. Calculations made on http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/Transistor_Circuits/

Due to the very low available current from receiver output pin, a high hFE transistor is required. [2N2222](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/PN/PN2222A.pdf) should work (its maximum hFE is 300).

Use a (transistor) driver. Something like:

[image]

Comment: Ya I thought it could be the amps, didn't relise I could break it through.. Will need to buy transistor. Additionally, are you recommending 2 power sources, or one but both input on both with more AMPS.

Comment: I've edited my suggest and added what I believe it is your suggesting.. can you confirm thats right or wrong, with any other improvements, :)

Comment: Is there any reason why you use the diode between the coil pins? I'm sure this has been asked time and time again on here, if you know a question / answer on here that may help then let me know. thx for all your help.

Comment: @bybe http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110574/how-to-choose-a-flyback-diode-for-a-relay and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115857/flyback-diodes-and-relays

Comment: Awesome, I'll read that in a moment. In the meantime I'm ordering the parts which is a 10K resistor, a 2N2222A Transistor... the diode, should any work?

Comment: Sorry, but you know mention 1.8K resistor, is this instead of the 10K as previously discussed?

Comment: @bybe yes, instead of the 10 k resistor.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Cornelius, I'm not thinking of using a 12v receiver, obviously the current will change so I guess I will need a different resistor would 3K be good enough?