# Choosing the correct flyback diode (if necessary at all)

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, flyback

I came up with this simple circuit to drive a couple of PC fans ON and OFF from a Raspberry Pi's GPIO pin:

[image: TIP122_as_fan_switch]

Probably I need a flyback diode somewhere, but at this point I don't know where and how to choose it (and if it's really necessary).

Any hint? Thanks.

EDIT: (if may help) I noticed that the fans are "brushless"... Does it mean I can go without diode?

Comment: you need a diode between the +12V rail and the collector, with the anode towards the +12v. If these are simply case fans, you will not need a diode, as the fans will have them built in.

Comment: @tuskiomi  I would still add a diode: it's a cheap insurance, and it doesn't hurt anything.  Use a fast Schottky diode.  For a moderately sized PC fan, I use B340 (or some such Schottky diode rated for 2A to 3A).  Don't use 1N4001, because they are too slow for a flyback diode.

Comment: Thanks guys. In addition, I noticed that the fans are "brushless"... Does it mean I can go without diode? [updating the question]

Comment: If you are only making a small number, e.g. one I'd add the diode it costs almost nothing and does no harm.

Comment: We communicate circuits with schematics here, not cartoons.

Comment: @OlinLathrop oohhh... I'm really sorry if I might have hit your sensibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a flyback diode?
The answer is **yes**.

The equivalent (simplified) circuit of a BLCD motor is:

[image]

You have a inductance and thus you need a flyback diode.

Usually you need to put a diode across the coil, as tuskiomi said in comment.

Some useful links:

1. [This is exactly your circuit](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/m5/tutorials/tip122_transistor_tutorial.html)
2. [A question that explain diodes in this circuits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93452/104387)
3. [Another similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/31014/104387)

Comment: Grazie  tante :)